# android layout dot points

Tags: android, drag-and-drop, points

I would like to know if there is a way of creating points inside an android layout. Im creating an app which creates comic strips. Im figuring out how users are gonna use images to drag and drop inside each strip/panel of a comics and came up with the idea of using points or dots inside a layout which would serve as the reciever of the images once the users drag and drop the image. Suggestions are appreciated.